# Changing column value on a CSV file

Tags: sql, regex, csv

I've been trying to do this through search only and failed. Would you guys be so kind and help me with this issue?

I have a CSV file that contains dozen columns and several thousand rows. The issue is that due to recent changes, one of the column values (grade) became deprecated.

There used to be 4 'grade tiers' and now they raised the tiers to 5, re-arranging the data between them.

I'm trying to find a way to use regex (or perhaps another method) to match the character extracted from a updated table (that is on an order that doesn't match the old CSV order) to one of the old table and if they're the same, change the value of the grade column.

For example:

(old file)

```
Character  Grade
  Y,          4       
  X,          4
  Foo,        2
  Bar,        0
```

(new file)

```
Character  Grade
  Y,         5
  X,         4
  Foo,       2
  Bar,       1
```

My idea is to use a conditional to match a character from new with one from old and if they're the same, change the grade value on the old file to match the updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex here is not very efficient but here is a pattern for you

```
^(\s*([^,]*),\s*)\d+(?=.*?new file.*?\2,\s*(\d+))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/31)

You're better off using Excel's built-in function `VLOOKUP`

[image]